# How to automatically disable and enable scroll for pre tag

Tags: html, scroll, overflow, pre

I need to implement down and up scroll when height of pre will be became more than X px. My friend behind cell phone says you can, and you need define maximum px of pre tag and when pre overflow, it must be visible, but I don't know css well and I couldn't implement this.

UPDATE:

Indeed U need to if my lines bigger than X line scroll enable and else it's invisible.

Can you put this code?

Comment: You need to formulate the requirements more clearly and to show (with HTML and CSS code) your best effort so far, and explain what needs to be improve. StackOverflow is not for writing code for your but for mutual help in solving problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this it will work,

```
pre{
width:100px;/*set appropriate width you want*/
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Take a look at this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/04qf1shv/

Comment: @Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh Without using any event how could it be possible?

Comment: I said, my event is : (if x>100px) Then scroll will be visilbed, It's possible with CSS?